# Is there a way to disable the automatic decrease in volume when I put an AUX cable/head phones in?

Tags: music-player, volume-control, headphones, volume

Phone specs:

- Phone: **LG G3**
- Android Version: **6.0**
- Software Version: **D85230e**

Situation:

I use an AUX cable to listen to music from my phone in my car. The only way to get the volume to the appropriate level is to turn my phone volume up to the maximum then adjust the car volume accordingly. Unfortunately, I have to repeat this process every time because if the volume was at max the previous time I used the AUX cable I get the following warning:

[image: Warning]

Question:

**Is there a way to disable this automatic decrease in volume so that when I plug the AUX cable in the volume will already be at the previous level (maximum)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a macro on [macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en) that does exactly this (not quite sure how to disable that setting itself but maybe a dev option). When you install the app, add a macro with "Headphones Inserted as trigger and "Volume Change" as the action. Now it will automatically set the media volume to your choosing when you insert headphones.

[image: macro for volume change]

Comment: That app is actually pretty awesome. Unfortunately, even with the above macro set the phone still lowers the volume.  The macro seems to be applied BEFORE the phone checks to see if the volume is too high.

Comment: That being said, I'm going to try to change the macro a bit so that it's trigger when the music app is opened with the headphones in as a constraint.

Comment: It works fine, I just need to make sure I have the AUX cable in before starting the music app. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome. If it doesn't work immediately then try setting "wait before next action"  for however much time you want before it does  the volume change.  This way it'll work every time.